# Flutter Provider: "ProxyFutureProvider" or similar

Tags: flutter, dart, proxy, provider

As I understand the concept of Proxy Providers allows us to use the value of another provider in another. How does one inject the value of a FutureProvider into another FutureProvider? I thought there would be a FutureProxyProvider, but there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: I am also wondering, did you have any solution?